# I can't figure out why my systemd service fails to create a /var/run/redis

Tags: server, 16.04, systemd

This is in ubuntu-16.04

I tried to write a custom redis service in /etc/system/systemd/redis-custom.service

The service fails (though redis starts , and restarts)  because /var/run/redis doesn't exist and it can't read the pidfile

The default redis-service creates /var/run using tmpfiles.d

```
cat /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/redis-server.conf
d /run/redis 2775 redis redis -
```

I wanted to consolidate this into just the service file, so I looked at the opendkim implementation in /lib/system/systemd/opendkim.service which used a different strategy of putting the mkdir in the service file before shedding privileges:

```
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=-/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/opendkim
ExecStartPre=-/bin/chown opendkim.opendkim /var/run/opendkim
```

Great idea.  So I tried using that for redis:

```
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=-/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/redis
ExecStartPre=-/bin/chown redis.redis /var/run/redis
```

That fails every time on the mkdir for lack of privileges.  I set up an empty server to test this and am only running redis/opendkim on it so I can try and find what files opendkim might be doing differently.  I can't figure this out.

I can make the directory for redis by specifying  `RuntimeDirectory=/var/run/redis` - which is a better solution.  HOWEVER I want to understand why the opendkim implementation is working. I seem to be missing something.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the same issue for about 1 hour...

**TL;DR:** You should comment out the

`ReadOnlyDirectories=-/`

in

`/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service`

and issue as `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

**Detailed explanation:**

I am running Redis 3.2.6 on a Raspian Strech 9.4 OS and have mounted `/var/log` as `tmpfs` to lower the amount of writes on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+'s microSD card.

```
ExecStartPre=-/bin/mkdir /var/log/redis
ExecStartPre=-/bin/chmod 750 /var/log/redis
ExecStartPre=-/bin/chown redis:redis /var/log/redis
```

I've also added some pre start commands in Redis's service file as shown above, but it still did not manage to create the directory as it was complaining of weird `Read-only file system` issue when starting up:

```
May 08 19:17:48 pisky systemd[1]: Starting Advanced key-value store...
-- Subject: Unit redis-server.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- Unit redis-server.service has begun starting up.
May 08 19:17:48 pisky mkdir[20564]: /bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/log/redis’: Read-only file system
May 08 19:17:48 pisky chmod[20567]: /bin/chmod: cannot access '/var/log/redis': No such file or directory
May 08 19:17:48 pisky chown[20570]: /bin/chown: cannot access '/var/log/redis': No such file or directory
May 08 19:17:49 pisky run-parts[20572]: run-parts: executing /etc/redis/redis-server.pre-up.d/00_example
May 08 19:17:49 pisky redis-server[20580]: *** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
May 08 19:17:49 pisky redis-server[20580]: Reading the configuration file, at line 163
May 08 19:17:49 pisky redis-server[20580]: >>> 'logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server.log'
May 08 19:17:49 pisky redis-server[20580]: Can't open the log file: No such file or directory
May 08 19:17:49 pisky wpa_supplicant[457]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
May 08 19:17:49 pisky systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 08 19:17:49 pisky systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
```

It seems that using its service file has some contradicting parameters, namely these:

```
# had to comment the below out, apparently this RO is exclusive
#ReadOnlyDirectories=-/
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/lib/redis
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/log/redis
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/run/redis
```

The `ReadOnlyDirectories` directive sets `/` as read only, but since `/var/log/` is mounted under `/` it's also set as read only...
This issue has been [described on Github](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7153), and I tried the respective proposed solutions, yet none of them work, apart from commenting out the above line...